# Set default application to "Ask always"?

Tags: default-programs

I open PDF files in different applications (Evince, Foxit, Master-pdf) each time depending on what I am doing. Is there a way to unset the default PDF application and allow me to choose an application to launch when I open a PDF file?

In other words, I would like the following menu to appear without choosing `Open with other application` option. That would make it easier to choose the application when opening a file from a launcher.

[image]

P.S. I am working on Ubuntu 20.04. Currently, I am using Ulauncher to launch applications and files.

Comment: Right click --> Open with --> Use the one you need.

Comment: That works when I use the file browser to reach the file. But I cannot do that when I use a laucher like Ulauncher or synapse

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1341192/edit) your question and add more details about what you are trying to do and also what version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: This would have to be something that Ulauncher supports then.  It is a 3rd party app that is not included into the default Ubuntu repositories so you couldn't file a bug against it for a feature request.  I would recommend that you file a feature request with the people that make Ulauncher.

Comment: That's true, but the same feature is lacking in every launcher including Ubuntu's default launcher also.

Comment: Even if we remove 3rd party apps out of the picture, at least one feature request with Ubuntu might be required, which can be either one of the two: to show an "open with" menu like my question suggests, or the Ubuntu launcher allows choosing an application

Comment: It is all feature requests for things that do not come by default in any of the applications and all of them are filed as `ubuntu-bug <application name>`.

Answer (score 0):

If the "Open with other application" view can be triggered from the cli you **could** do this if you create a desktop entry to wrap that command and set the mimetype for pdf for it, and probably set NoDisplay=true.

Hopefully Ulauncher will get to support this eventually, but it's not a trivial change and we would probably want to have it fully integrated in Ulauncher.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But is there a command to "open with other applications" ?